# vb.net - webbrowser get xml document

Tags: xml, vb.net, com, browser, webbrowser-control

Hey, I have been trying to switch my code from using an ie object to using a built in webbrowser. Most of the properties are the same but I have run into an issue getting an xmldocument from a page.

```
'Internet Explorer Object
Dim oXML As Object = oIE.document.XMLDocument
nodeList = oXML.SelectNodes(path).length
```

Trying this method on webbrowser obviously doesn't work. But does anyone know the path to get the XMLDocument object from webbrowser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

`WebBrowser1.Document.DomDocument.XMLDocument`